# display dialogue immediately after selecting value in selectonemenu

Tags: primefaces

I have a requirement with p:selectonemenu when I am using inside dataTable.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{buyerInProcessBean.subject}"
                            id="buyerResponseId" >
                            <f:selectItems
                                value="#{buyerInProcessBean.subjectMap[trans.decisionrule.ruleId]}"
                                var="subject" itemLabel="#{subject}" itemValue="#{subject}"></f:selectItems>
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="Other"></f:selectItem>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

If I choose 'other' a dialogue must compulsory get popup. otherwise it is not mandatory.

How can I achieve this type of requirement?

Comment: you can add onSelect="your dialogWidgetVar.show()" in the selectOneMenu

Comment: @Ali:There is no onSelect attribute on selectOneMenu. May be it is onChange

Comment: But my requirement is only when we select 'other' dialogue has to pop-up. otherwise it is an optional(no need to pop-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind a function to an `onchange` event of your `<p:selectOneMenu>`, find out if the value of the desired option matches the value that should open the dialog, and trigger `dialog.open()` in that case.

Note, that Primefaces' component wraps the `<select>` tag within some divs and outputs the selected `<option>` in an intermediary component, therefore attachment of event to the hidden `<select>` element won't work. On the other hand, for example, JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag renders a `<select>` element, so binding behaviour to the `onchange` will trigger the desired behaviour.

The view:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{buyerInProcessBean.subject}" id="buyerResponseId" onchange="changeEvent(this)">
        <f:selectItems value="#{buyerInProcessBean.subjectMap[trans.decisionrule.ruleId]}" 
                       var="subject" itemLabel="#{subject}" itemValue="#{subject}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="Other" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog">
    <h:outputText value="Additional Data" />
</p:dialog>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function changeEvent(element) {
    var val = $(element).find('option:selected').text();
    if(val === 'Other') {
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```